# How to reuse SSL connection from .NET client to Apache Server

Tags: .net, apache, ssl, reusability, keep-alive

- We are consuming an HTTPS REST based webservice that is written in Apache.
- Our client is written in .NET framework 4.5 using System.Net.Http library and class HttpClient to connect.
- The REST based webservice that we consume requires us to attach a certificate in the header.
- The above works just fine. But since there is an SSL negotiation involved, the requests take a long time to execute (300ms per request).

Question: How can I configure/code SSL session re-use in .NET client library so that the subsequent Https connections do not have to handshake and the performance is improved.

Here's all that I tried but didn't help:

1. Tried to set httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Connection.TryParseAdd("Keep-alive"); //Here httpClient is an instance of HttpClient class.
2. Tried changing the casing of keep-alive
3. Set Tcp Keep alive using System.Net.ServicePointManager.SetTcpKeepAlive(true, 10000, 3000); // this is to say that since SSL re-negotiation happens on TCP, keep Tcp alive.
4. Set the MaxConnections value in web.config that connects the http REST server to 12.

Another interesting aspect: When the REST API implementers call the HTTPS REST url using Jmeter with keep-alive header, they are able to re-use the ssl connection and performance is good (with - 63ms and without - 300ms).

Can someone please help on what am I missing from my settings on .NET side.

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved now. The problem was my understanding of HttpClient class. The way it works is that an instance of HttpClient creates a pool of connections for every instance created. Once we move the httpclient to a global or class level context such that in repeated calls the instance is not re-created, it works like a charm.